Resolving conflicts in Bitbucket Automatic merge failure PRs
The repository has Automatic branch merging set up to automatically merge changes from branch release/1.0 to release/2.0 upon PR merges on release/1.0. release/2.0 already has feature B code that should only exist in 2.0 release. When another feature A's code is merged to release/1.0, an automatic merge from release/1.0 to release/2.0 is attempted by the Automatic branch merging feature. If there's no conflicts, the attempt should succeed, and having feature A in both 1.0 and 2.0 releases is desired. However, when merge conflicts occur, an "Automatic merge failure" PR is raised by Bitbucket between sourcing branch release/1.0 and targeting branch release/2.0, and a conflict resolution is demanded.
My question is how to resolve this conflict without release/1.0 acquiring the feature B code from release/2.0 branch.
The version of Bitbucket Server is 7.21
